# requestAnimationFrame CPU 170%

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, requestanimationframe

I have an `interval` inside `onPlayerStateChange` function which updates the `progress` element value using `requestAnimationFrame`. The problem is that the CPU usage goes form `90% to 170%`. I have tried to clear the requestAnimationFrame when the progress value is the same as Y param and when the video is not playing but it is still the same. Also `console.log('Y')` keeps logging thousands of times. It logs even when I pause the video, it just won't stop.

What is the problem here?

```
var pFrame;//global


function scrollP(Y, duration, easingFunction) {

    var start = Date.now(),
        elem = document.getElementById('progress'),
        from = elem.value;

    if(from === Y) {
        window.cancelAnimationFrame(pFrame);
        return; /* Prevent scrolling to the Y point if already there */
    }

    function min(a,b) {return a < b ? a : b}

    function scroll() {//this is the animatin frame
        console.log('Y');

        var time = min(1, ((Date.now() - start) / duration)),
            easedT = easingFunction(time);

        elem.value = (easedT * (Y - from)) + from;

        pFrame = requestAnimationFrame(scroll);
    }

    pFrame = requestAnimationFrame(scroll)
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    //clear interval when not playing
    //clear pFrame
    if(player.getPlayerState() != 1) {
        window.cancelAnimationFrame(pFrame);
        clearInterval(to);
    }

    if(event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        to = setInterval(function() {
            (duration > 0) ? value = 1 / duration * player.getCurrentTime() : 0;
            //here I call the pFrame function
            pFrame = scrollP(value, 1000, easing.linear)
        }, 50);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're setting `pFrame` to `undefined` every time you start a loop (`pFrame = scrollP(value, 1000, easing.linear)`) so  you're not actually clearing any of your animation frame handlers.

Comment: Isn't it a global var? the pFrame?

Comment: why `scrollP(value, 1000, easing.linear)` is undefined ?

Comment: Yes but that doesn't change the fact that `pFrame = scrollP(...)` means `pFrame = undefined`. You aren't returning anything from `scrollP`.

Comment: And what should I do ? return a value from `scrollP`?

Comment: Only assign to `pFrame` with `requestAnimationFrame`. Then you can just call `scrollP` by itself. No reason to assign it's return value to something.

Comment: Can you post it as an answer so I can be more clear please?

Comment: I'm feel pretty sure the CPU cannot go to 170%...

Comment: Its what Activity Monitor tells

Comment: Go home Activity Monitor, you're %*)...

Comment: Its not  only Activity Monitor, Safari freezes also

Comment: @rexhin it's the setInterval that fires outside time budget accumulating events that cannot be finished in time, eventually coming to an halt. Mike C has you covered.

Comment: So you also think to remove set interval? But I need to get the value of `player.getCurrentTime()` every x milliseconds

Comment: @rexhin there shouldn't be need to obtain current time below <16ms (60 fps) or in most cases <33ms (25-30fps) . requestAnimationFrame should hold for this purpose and there may be other factors preventing the browser to finish on time causing a halt with setInterval

Comment: And how can I get rid of that? Can you help me to move the logic outside the setInterval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning `undefined` to `pFrame`. This means you never clear any queued up frames.

The way this happens is with this line:

```
pFrame = scrollP(value, 1000, easing.linear)
```

Every function in JavaScript returns `undefined` unless you explicitly tell it not to. You should only ever assign the return value of a function if you actually plan to use that return value.

Instead, you should only assign to `pFrame` with `requestAnimationFrame`.

So change this:

```
pFrame = scrollP(value, 1000, easing.linear)
```

to this:

```
scrollP(value, 1000, easing.linear)
```

Again, if you aren't returning anything from a function, there's no reason to use it's return value.

Comment: @rexhin Why are you using `setInterval` at all? It's probably related to that. You're just creating more and more event handlers. Just create one loop with `requestAnimationFrame` and do all of your logic in there.

Comment: Yes I think setInterval is the problem too. How can I do that? I need to calculate` player.getCurrentTime()`. Can you help me please? to get rid of that interval

Comment: @rexhin I don't think you need to calculate `player.getCurrentTime()`. It's being given to you. I think you need to really think about what exactly you're trying to do and put it together slowly.

Comment: I need to update progress value every x milliseconds for ex. and i need to pause that when video is not playing or pause

Comment: @rexhin There you go. So just use `requestAnimationFrame` to create a loop and only do the logic inside of it when the player is in the correct state.

Comment: `player.getCurrentTime()` only works inside `onPlayerStateChange`

Comment: @rexhin Why? You aren't getting the `player` variable through that event. What happens if you call `player.getCurrentTime()` outside of `onPlayerStateChange`?

Comment: It is YouTube API. It returns always 0 outside that

Comment: @rexhin I'm sorry but that's not true at all. [It's updated periodically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650281/how-to-detect-change-in-youtube-getcurrenttime), that doesn't mean it's only available when that event is fired.

Comment: yes It is, see the first answer of that question. When I try to alert player.getCurrentTime() outside that it returns always 0.

Comment: it needs to change when the video pauses/ plays/ buffers

Comment: @rexhin I did read it. Did you? They literally suggested setting up an asynchronous loop and checking for the value that way. They in no way said you have to handle it during that event. It's a coincidence that the value has changed when that event fires. `onPlayerStateChange` only fires when switching between states like "playing" and "paused." `player.getCurrentTime()` should be updated more often than that.

Comment: @rexhin You need to get some fundamentals of JavaScript down. Without those fundamentals (return values, asynchronous functions) you are not going to be able to design your code in such a way that it works correctly.

Comment: I know I am not an expert, im trying to do what you are saying but its not working.

Comment: @rexhin Like I said, you need to get some fundamentals down. Set aside all of the YouTube API stuff and really, really learn how `requestAnimationFrame` works. After you understand that, you should be able to figure out the rest.